# Parse number from text in select dropdown to calculate the number and save both text and number to DB

Tags: javascript

I have a select dropdown with a number value only but the user sees a descriptor for a service attached to the amount

```
<option value="400">New Report</option>
```

So long as the value is a pure #, all the javascript code I use runs all the calcs and totals nicely.

The issue is I can't figure out how to save the number and the descriptor at the same time so the form still calculates and I know the choice the user made.

If I include the text to be parsed with php later on to split the number from the text and save in 2 fields in the DB, my calc result is 'NaN' because text is present in the value field

I have tried to somehow split the number from the text in the onchange event, but that has not worked

eg

```
<select id="srv1" name="srv1" onChange="calcexp(this.form,str.split('srv1','-','0'));">
```

the idea is to draw from the value what is on the left of the dash.

as in

```
 <option value="400-New Report">New Report</option>
```

Comment: I couldn't get your question. Please simplify.

Comment: You should probably read the documentation for [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Also `str` doesn't appear to be defined in code shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to create an attribute in all options which has option numeric value. And for calculation, you can pass numeric value by getting attribute. Check below code:

```
    <select id="srv1" name="srv1" onChange="calcexp(this.form, this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-value'));">
        <option value="400-new" data-value="400">New Report</option>
        <option value="500-old" data-value="500">old  Report</option>
    </select>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Good practice is to use `data-` attributes for custom data, not something like `attr-value`

Comment: Thanks @pete I will surely follow this from now.

Comment: I tried 'data-value' and 'srv1', but the value is not picked up. Still get NaN. If there was a way to POST the 'data-value- variable, then I could get that to work

Comment: Can you show your code to me, so I can check? I have checked my shared code and it is working fine.

Comment: I didn't want to fight all the other code that did the calcs so I used this sample and it works now `<select id=srv1 name=srv1 onChange="calcexp(this.form,'srv1');"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="400" data-service="New R">New Report</option>
</select>

<input type=hidden name=service id=service />

<script>
$('#srv1').change(function () {
var service=$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-service');
$('#service').val(service);
});
</script>` **then:** `$service = $_POST['service'];`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you'd parse a number in a string to the left of a <kbd>-</kbd>

```js
let str = "123-etc";
let int = Number.parseInt(str.split("-", 1)[0]);
console.log(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use data attributes to store the extra text with html elements. You can read about data attributes here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes